# Power BI and Azure Document DB

Tags: powerbi, azure-cosmosdb

I have connected to Azure Document DB by Power BI ,but it is taking too much time for data to load and even more time to apply the queries ...Is there any way to reduce this data loading time??

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a generic question around Power BI and even broadly BI tools. But, in general, you have to specify more filters to the queries (yes, they can be edited even in plain SQL). Azure Cosmos DB is super-fast, it all depends on how much data you're trying to query. Also, make sure data is in the region from which users are accessing it in Power BI.